# Android: Repeat a dispatchKeyEvent while while a button is selected, focused, or pressed

Tags: java, android

My layout contains a button and an editText view. While the button is held down I want to have a keyboard key pressed over and over again until the button is released.
Here is the basic concept:

```
while(button is held down){

dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_P));

dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,
                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_P));

}
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

See [View#setOnTouchListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener%28android.view.View.OnTouchListener%29) and [View.OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html).  When you receive a `MotionEvent` with `ACTION_DOWN`, you would start some repetition (e.g., create a `Handler` in your Activity, and call [Handler#sendMessageDelayed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendMessageDelayed%28android.os.Message,%20long%29), where the delay is whatever repeat delay you want to use.  As each message is received, you would first perform your key dispatches, and then call `sendMessageDelayed()` again to schedule the next key press.  On `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`, you would call [Handler#removeMessages()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeMessages%28int%29) to cancel the pending scheduled event.

As for simulating the keypress events, the `dispatchKeyEvent()` method you described might work, depending on what you want to achieve:  would have to explain further, if that doesn't work for you.